# Is it possible to add/remove HTML Attributes for every formfield in Django

Tags: python, django

My goal is to remove the required tag from every formfield in my django app.

I want to remove the required html attribute, because I have my own error handling and I don't want the required tooltips of html.

[image]

The problem is that I've installed some 3rd party libraries and I want to remove it from their forms either.

I thought about creating a custom Formrenderer, but I'm not sure how or maybe you have another idea.

Comment: what should happen, if a field in the corresponding models.py is mandatory but not in your form? Also, some code (forms.py, views.py etc) would be helpful.

Comment: no it should be mandatory in both, but I want to remove the html required tag, because I have my own error handling and I don't want these html tooltips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set any html attribute in the `__init__` method.

You can also use `self.fields` to iterate over fields. See the following form for an example:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_('Search'))
    l = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_('Location'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["q"].disabled = True
        self.fields["q"].required = True
        self.fields["q"].widget.attrs["readonly"] = True
        self.fields['q'].widget.attrs['id'] = 'search_type'
        self.fields['q'].widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
        self.fields['q'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = _("Function, Keyword or Company")
        self.fields['q'].widget.attrs.update({'class':"browser-default material-ignore search-input"})

        # iterate over fields
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].required = False
```

UPDATE

---

You can also use javascript (jQuery or something else) to remove required attribute on client side. If you want disable it on server side, you have to override `django-allauth` forms.

[**django-allauth**](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#forms) has great documentation.

You can override some forms in django-allauth, see the following example:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm, LoginForm


class MyCustomLoginForm(LoginForm):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        # iterate over fields
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].required = False

    def login(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Add your own processing here.

        # You must return the original result.
        return super(MyCustomLoginForm, self).login(*args, **kwargs)


class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        # iterate over fields
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].required = False

    def save(self, request):

        # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
        # .save() returns a User object.
        user = super(MyCustomSignupForm, self).save(request)

        # Add your own processing here.

        # You must return the original result.
        return user
```

**settings.py**:

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'login': 'mysite.forms.MyCustomLoginForm',
    'signup': 'mysite.forms.MyCustomSignupForm'
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to override every 3rd party form

Comment: I want to disable the html required tags globally, if thats possible

Comment: @tommypre,  Your question is not clear. Provide some example in your question. What do you want exactly? If you only need change required attribute for all fields simply use `self.fields [field] .required = False`. I updated my answer.

Comment: @tommypre, ok i see now. Simply use the last example from my answer. That will do whatever you want.

Comment: @tommypre, Share your `forms.py` so I can help you further.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, for example I use [AllAuth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/) and I want to remove the HTML required tags from every of the forms. I wanted to know, if it's possible to set this globally or if i have to override these forms and use your method. This is quite elaborate for every 3rd party form. I hope this helps to understand my problem.

Comment: @tommypre, You can also use javascript (jQuery or something else) to remove required attribute on client side. If you want disable it on server side, you have to override django-allauth forms. I added some example to my answer.

Comment: thanks with js it's probably the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

I've disabled HTML form-validation with JQuery

```
$("form").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("novalidate", true)
});
```